# WCF Service in Azure WorkerRole for Silverlight application

Tags: wcf, azure, cross-domain

I have a Windows Azure WorkerRole which hosts a WCF Service. This service shall be consumed by a Silverlight application. Locally, this works fine, however, when I try to deploy it, the endpoint needs to be configured in the Role configuration (see image below).

[image]

When I delete that endpoint "WCFEndpoint", everything works fine locally. However, when it is there, the following exception occurs:

> System.ServiceModel.AddressAlreadyInUseException: HTTP konnte die URL
>   "http://+:9196/GreenwayService/" nicht registrieren, weil der TCP-Port
>   9196 von einer anderen Anwendung verwendet wird.

which means in English: HTTP could not register URL "...", because the TCP PORT 9196 is used by another application.

As far as I understand, the endpoint needs to be defined like in the picture in order to be accessible inside the cloud.

Here is my app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.diagnostics>
        <trace>
            <listeners>
                <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" name="AzureDiagnostics">
                    <filter type=""/>
                </add>
            </listeners>
        </trace>
    </system.diagnostics>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup><system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="Greenway.AzureWorkerRole.ServiceHosting.CrossDomainService">
                <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="HttpEnableBehavior"
                    binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Greenway.AzureWorkerRole.ServiceHosting.ICrossDomainService" />
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:9196/" />
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
            </service>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="GreenwayServiceBehavior" name="Greenway.AzureWorkerRole.ServiceHosting.GreenwayService">
                <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Greenway.AzureWorkerRole.ServiceHosting.IGreenwayService" />
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:9196/GreenwayService/" />
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
            </service>
        </services>

        <behaviors>
          <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="HttpEnableBehavior">
              <webHttp/>
            </behavior>
          </endpointBehaviors>

          <serviceBehaviors>

            <behavior name="GreenwayServiceBehavior">
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

And this is the code snippet starting the services:

```
ServiceHost greenwayServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(GreenwayService));
ServiceHost crossDomainServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(CrossDomainService));
greenwayServiceHost.Open();
crossDomainServiceHost.Open();
```

What do I need to change inside those three places in order to host the services inside the cloud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost issue is that you are using "localhost" as binding address. This will never work in Windows Azure. All the traffic in Windows Azure is directed (from the Load Balancers) to the physical internal IP address (also called DIP or Direct IP Address) of the role instance (VM).

In order to make things working in windows azure you have to bind to the DIP (Direct IP Address) of the instance of the Role and to use the port porvided by the Input Endpoint. I do it like that (for Worker Role and self hosted WCF):

```
 private void CreateServiceHost()
    {
        this._serviceHost = new UnityServiceHost(typeof(MyService));

        var binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
        RoleInstanceEndpoint externalEndPoint =
            RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints["ServiceEndpoint"];
        string endpoint = String.Format(
            "net.tcp://{0}/MyService", externalEndPoint.IPEndpoint);
        this._serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyService), binding, endpoint);
        this._serviceHost.Open();
    }
```

And this works in 100% in local dev and real live Azure environment. The thing to note here is that I building my endpoint dynamically out from the IPEndpoint instance of my Role's Input Endpoint.

I'm pretty sure your services will work as expected once you bind them to the actual IP Address **and port** which you take from the RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints["WCFEndpoint"];

Comment: Thanks for the good explanation. I tried this and it works locally as well in the cloud. There is just one problem: With my previous solution I was able to consume the WCF service using the "Add Service Reference"-Window inside Visual Studio. I just had to enter the address and it would find the service and create the reference automatically. With the modified version, it is not possible to add that referece. Do you know why that is? Could it be the CrossDomain thing? The workaround I'm now using is to initially add the reference using my old code and then change the code.

Comment: Hm, with my solution I was using manual serviceclient created based on the contract. However from within Visual Studio, instead of typing the address to find the service, you could try the "Discover Services in Solution". That way VS might be able to find the service and create the local service proxy classes (I'm not sure about that though).